# Sort Set when only specific objects are comparable

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I have a Set of unique data. Let's say it looks like this:

```
0: domainA.org -> domainB.org
1: domainY.org -> domainZ.org
2: domainB.org -> domainC.org
3: domainD.org -> domainE.org
4: domainX.org -> domainY.org
5: domainC.org -> domainD.org
```

In order to copy data related to `domainA.org` to B C D and E and `doimanY.org` to X and Z, I need to iterate over this set in the following order:

```
0: domainA.org -> domainB.org
2: domainB.org -> domainC.org
5: domainC.org -> domainD.org
3: domainD.org -> domainE.org

4: domainX.org -> domainY.org
1: domainY.org -> domainZ.org
```

It doesn't matter if `X -> Y -> Z` is processed before `A -> B -> C -> D -> E` they aren't related to each other.

Sorting each "category" e.g. every independend part of data on its own is fairly easy.
I made my wrapper object for `sourceDomain -> destinationDomain` implement Comparable and used a SortedSet to do the sorting for me.
Now here's the problem.
This is what my comparteTo implementation looks like:

```
if (source.equals(other.destination)) {
    return 1;
} else if (destination.equals(other.source)) {
    return -1;
}
return 0;
```

It is only able to compare 2 objects if they are next to each other in the final list otherwhise it "treats" the other objects as the same.
(Not to mention that TreeSet isn't adding items to itself if compareTo returns 0 at some point)
Because of that it's not sorting the data I showed in example 1 correctly.
My Idea would be to iterate over the source set and add compare the entries against every other entry and create seperate sets which i can join together once I finished sorting.
The complexity of this would at least be n^2 which is pretty bad.
My question: Can we do better than that?

Comment: what about when source not equals other.destination and also destination not equals other.source ? in this case the method returns 0

Comment: Correct, this is the problem... There's no way to determine how those 2 objects relate to each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is a topological sort in a graph. There are various algorithms that can solve this, available in pseudo code on [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

The easiest to implement is a depth-first-search, somewhat copied below:

```
L ← Empty list that will contain the sorted nodes
foreach node n do
    if not marked n then visit(n) 

function visit(node n)
    if n has a temporary mark then stop (cyclic dependency found!)
    if n is not marked (i.e. has not been visited yet) then
        mark n temporarily
    for each node m with an edge from n to m do
        visit(m)
        mark n permanently
        unmark n temporarily
        add n to head of L
```

This has at most time complexity O(nodes + edges), and in your case it would seem that nodes = edges, so that would be fast enough.